# Why dynamically creating Aura Component not working if access level is not defined?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, dynamic

I have a code that creates an Aura component dynamically.

```
$A.createComponent('c:HelloWorld', (content, status, message) => {
     console.log('Status : '+ status); // Status : ERROR
     console.log('message : ' + message); // message : Unknown component 'markup://c:HelloWorld'.
});
```

The component was working earlier but after the last release (Probably after Salesforce Spring 2020 release) it stopped working and I am getting above error.

When I add access level of the component to global `access="global"` it works fine.

I want to know if adding `access="global"` is a salesforce recommendation or I am missing any permission.

Additional information: **HelloWorld** also have an apex controller and I am running code as **System administrator**.

Comment: You should be using $A.createComponents. The method you are calling is deprecated. How is this dynamic code being used? Context matters. It may be that global access is necessary, or it may simply be a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Order to [create a component dynamically from JS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm), you need to declare the component a [dependency in component markup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_dependency.htm)

**Test.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://c:sample" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

**TestController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.createComponent('c:sample', {}, (content, status, message) => {

            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var body = component.get("v.body");
                body.push(content);
                component.set("v.body", body);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

> NOTE: The error you mentioned may also come when you are creating
>   component [outside framework lifecycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm), in that case, wrap the
>   function call in $A.getCallback()

Comment: You do not need aura:dependency except when using Lightning Out. Using is this way is optional, with a tradeoff of more upfront loading time for faster rendering when called.